# Latitude of Impact of a satellite

Tags: orbital-motion, celestial-mechanics, satellites

I'm currently studying orbital mechanics, and am tasked with finding the latitude of impact of a suborbital satellite, given its location and velocity in geocentric coordinates at some time.

Assume the planet is spherical, other forces than the 2 bodies are negligible, and ignore atmospheric drag. The orbit is elliptical and will impact at some point.

I've already calculated the classical orbital elements, and just need to find the latitude (the inclination is 90 degrees, so latitude could be anywhere). Here's my line of thinking:

I have $\vec{e}$ which points in the direction of Periapse, and I can solve for the true anomaly at the time when $r_i = 1DU = \frac{p}{1-ecos(\nu_i)}$, and thus have $\nu_i$, the angle from Periapse to impact site in the orbital plane. In Perifocal Coordinates, $\vec{P} = normalize(\vec{e})$ and $\vec{Q} = normalize(\vec{\vec{h}\times\vec{P}})$, and thus $\vec{r_i} = r_icos(\nu_i)\vec{P} + r_isin(\nu_i)\vec{Q}$.

We can transform that to geocentric coordinates ($\vec{I}$,$\vec{J}$,$\vec{K}$) and thus get $\vec{r_i}$ in geocentric coordinates. Since latitude is measured from the $\vec{I}\vec{J}$ plane, we can use the dot product between $\vec{r_i}$ and the equatorial plane to find it.

This seems to make sense, but I can't find any sources describing this specific problem, nor answers to the specific question I'm trying to answer (converting orbital elements to latitude and longitude). I also suspect there is a simpler way to do this.

Comment: Any updates in this?
I have the same issue.

Comment: @MacacusRectus, this might be a good question for https://space.stackexchange.com/